# Watching high definition Youtube videos on PlayStation 3

Tags: ps3

I have a PlayStation 3 and a HDTV, but I am unable to watch high definition video in 1080. It seems like lower resolutions are selected by default.

Is there a way to change the resolution of the video?

Comment: What is the source of the video?  Is the source in 1080p?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When visiting the YouTube site on the PS3 you get redirected to their special "TV" landing page, which plays with a ridiculously low resolution. Try visiting [PS3 YouTube](http://www.ps3youtube.com/) instead.